# Javascript dynamic element creation leads to shadow content in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I create a class and elements inside the class using the following function in javascript and add it to another class using appendchild function.

```
function createClass(menu)
{
                console.log('class entered');
                var newNode = document.createElement('div');
                newNode.className = 'item';
                
                
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
                input.setAttribute("id",menu);
                input.innerText=menu;
                var label = document.createElement('label');
                label.setAttribute("for", menu);
                label.innerText=menu;

                input.appendChild(label);
                newNode.appendChild(input);
               return newNode;

        }
```

But, the contents is not displayed in the html page. The class is added. When the body of the html is displayed in the console, the class is added to the body but before the inner text, it says "shadow content (user Agent)".

How do I make them visible?

Answer (score 0):

You've create new DOM elements but never actually attached them to the current document. The missing part is to to add your new DOM element to the document:

```js
document.body.appendChild(createClass('hello'))
```

Comment: Yes, this is passed from an array of strings and it should be attached to another div class inside the html.

Comment: Another thing I would suggest is that `input` elements are not supposed to have children. So, you should be making `input` and `label` siblings and wrap them up in a parent.